# open URL in Safari instead of webView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rss

I have an app that populates an RSS feed in a table view. Selecting a row on the table, opens a new View with the whole post. My issue sometimes there are hyperlinks in the RSS feed. Clicking on the link opens the content in the same view instead of safari. I would like to open any links that are in the RSS feed in safari with an alert message about leaving the app. But I have no idea for to deal with this in my code. Any leads would be helpful. I am pasting my code for the DetailedView below.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.itemSummary loadHTMLString:[item objectForKey:@"summary"] baseURL:nil];
}


 - (id)initWithItem:(NSString *)theItem {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:nil]) {  
        self.item = theItem;  
        self.title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    }  

    return self;  
}
```

Comment: Just try `[UIApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myLink]]`, with your web view delegate.

Comment: The problem is I am not dealing with that part of the code at all and the links are dynamic based on the RSS feed.

Comment: If you look at the `UIWebViewDelegate` docs, you'll see that you can intercept the loading of a new page, and handle it differently (i.e. as mentioned above). The method to implement would be `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented the method and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

try this code:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```